# How to read password protected pdf using itextsharp in my code?

Tags: itext

in my C# window application i want to read the text & images from ABC.pdf but its password protected.please help me to solve this issue.

```
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"E:\ABC.pdf");

            int intPageNum = reader.NumberOfPages;
            string[] words;
            string line;

            for (int i = 1; i <= intPageNum; i++)
            {
               var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());

                words = text.Split('\n');
                for (int j = 0, len = words.Length; j < len; j++)
                {
                    line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(words[j]));
                    label1.Text = label1.Text + "\n" + line;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you have the password? And when you say password-protected, are you talking about a *user password*, an *owner password*, or both?

Comment: yes i have password but i dont want to pass and i am talking about both password.

Comment: *"i have password but i dont want to pass"* what do you mean by that?

Comment: I want to say that i have password of my pdf file but i don't want to pass/define in my code to read that pdf file. I found many example in which the PDF password is define in code and read the PDF document but thats not my requirement.